# How to use getStoreCategories function

Tags: magento-1.9, category, product-collection, programmatically

I am working on category collection, i find this [link](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-list-of-all-categories/). Here

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');

// sorted by name, fetched as collection
$categoriesCollection = $helper->getStoreCategories('name', true, false);

// sorted by name, fetched as array
$categoriesArray = $helper->getStoreCategories('name', false, false);
```

this lines of code are written but where store id is passed so that all category collection fetch.

Answer (score 3):

This function will load all categories from the root category of your current store.

```
$parent     = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
```

The store is loaded from the `Mage::app()->getStore()` function which will load the store based on a few settings.

If you do not pass an Id to the getStore function then it will load the current store.

```
$id = $this->_currentStore;
```

So whatever is your current store based on app initialization will be used in this function.